# Simplify Jquery code with attr()?

Tags: jquery, attr

I'am coding a Slider with different car types.

Now i have setup a code that targets every single class and ID but there should be a shorter way to do this?

Here a sample of my repeating jquery code:

```
$("a.id-159").on('click', function() {
    $('.car').find('.carBox.active').fadeOut(200);
    $('.ui-carousel').find('a.active').removeClass("active");
    $("a.id-159").addClass("active");
    $('#id-159').fadeIn(1000).addClass("active");
});

$("a.giulietta").on('click', function() {
    $('.car').find('.carBox.active').fadeOut(200);
    $('.ui-carousel').find('a.active').removeClass("active");
    $("a.giulietta").addClass("active");
    $('#giulietta').fadeIn(1000).addClass("active");
});
```

My HTML

```
<div id="carouselslider">
<div id="carousel">


        <a class="mito-qv" ><img src="tl_files/motorvillage/images/inhalte/NEUEWAGEN/alfa-romeo/thumb/MiToQV_thumb.jpg" alt="MiTo QV" width="150" height="107" />
        <span>MiTo QV</span></a>


        <a class="giulietta" ><img src="tl_files/motorvillage/images/inhalte/NEUEWAGEN/alfa-romeo/thumb/Giulietta_thumb.jpg" alt="Giulietta" width="150" height="107" />
        <span>Giulietta</span></a>


        <a class="id-159" ><img src="tl_files/motorvillage/images/inhalte/NEUEWAGEN/alfa-romeo/thumb/159MY_thumb.jpg" alt="159" width="150" height="107" />
        <span>159</span></a>


        <a class="id-159sw" ><img src="tl_files/motorvillage/images/inhalte/NEUEWAGEN/alfa-romeo/thumb/159STWI_thumb.jpg" alt="159SW" width="150" height="107" />
        <span>159SW</span></a>


        <a class="id-8c" ><img src="tl_files/motorvillage/images/inhalte/NEUEWAGEN/alfa-romeo/thumb/8C_Spider_thumb.jpg" alt="8C" width="150" height="107" />
        <span>8C</span></a>


</div>
<a href="#" id="ui-carousel-next"><span>next</span></a>
<a href="#" id="ui-carousel-prev"><span>prev</span></a>
```

Is there a way to shorten this?

Thx for your help!

Gr Rogier

Thanks for your Input!
I have combined the different Input to this:

```
$("#carousel").children("a").on('click', function() {
    $('.car').find('.carBox.active').fadeOut(200);
    $('.ui-carousel').find('a.active').removeClass("active");
    var h = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#'+h).fadeIn(1000).addClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

And it works perfectly :-)

Comment: So you have `.giuletta` and `#giuletta`? Are these different elements?

Comment: Yes, there those are different elements.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way to shorten it:

```
$("#carousel").children("a").on('click', function() {
    $('.car').find('.carBox.active').fadeOut(200);
    $('.ui-carousel').find('a.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).fadeIn(1000).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by combining selectors via `,`.

```
$("a.id-159, a.giulietta").on('click', function() {
    $('.car').find('.carBox.active').fadeOut(200);
    $('.ui-carousel').find('a.active').removeClass("active");

    if ($(this).hasClass('id-159')) {
        $('#id-159').fadeIn(1000).addClass("active");
        $("a.id-159").addClass("active");
    }
    else {
        $("a.giulietta").addClass("active");
        $('#giulietta').fadeIn(1000).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.id-159, a.giulietta").on('click', function() {
    $('.car').find('.carBox.active').fadeOut(200);
    $('.ui-carousel').find('a.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var h = $(this).attr('class').replace(/^.*(id-159|giulietta).*$/, "$1");
    $('#'+h).fadeIn(1000).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your Input!
I have combined the different Input to this:

Comment: Thanks for your Input!
I have combined the different Input to this:

    $("#carousel").children("a").on('click', function() {
        $('.car').find('.carBox.active').fadeOut(200);
     $('.ui-carousel').find('a.active').removeClass("active");
        var h = $(this).attr('class');
        $('#'+h).fadeIn(1000).addClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

And it works perfectly :-)